# Embedding swf into html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash

I've find some way to embed swf into html page... Here is code...

```
<object id="swfobj" style="display:none; margin-right: 385px;" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-    AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" 
    codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0"
    width="309" height="200">
<param name="movie">
<param name="quality" value="high">
  <embed  style="margin-left: 18px;border:1px solid #999999;" quality="high" width="309" height="200" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
</embed>
```

Then in JavaScript part I have this

```
function openfile(filePath) {
        $("#swfobj > EMBED").attr("src", filePath);
        $("#swfobj").fadeIn("slow");
    };
```

Now I've two problems

1.This code works in Firefox, but is crashed in Chrome... It works only when I clicked at first element and then it stop working... How to make this cross-browser?

2.I want to open  swf in a new tab of my browser... How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your function add:

```
my_window = window.open("myflash.html", "mywindow1", "status=1,width=309,height=200");
my_window.document.write($("#swfobj").html());
```

This will open a new window (myflash.html, you must create it) that contains the html of `object` with id `#swfobj`.

Keep in mind that you must make the `#swfobj` visible in the new window. So add

```
swfobj {
    display:block !important;
}
```

in the myflash.html (`!important` is needed to override the inline `display:none` of `#swfobj`

The above works in firefox and chrome but you have to enable the popup.